# AngularJS 1.2.15 and Restangular 1.3.1 problems

Tags: angularjs, restangular

I must be missing something very basic but I can't get Restangular to load.  My steps ...

1. Scaffold a new project with Yeoman
2. Insert includes for Lodash and Restangular
3. Inject restangular into my module.
4. grunt test

This is the result ...

```
Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module fooApp due to:
Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module restangular due to:
Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'restangular' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.
```

Here are my includes ...

```
<script src="bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-resource/angular-resource.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/lodash/dist/lodash.js">
<script src="bower_components/restangular/dist/restangular.js">
```

Yes, they are in my bower_components directory.

My module definition is ...

angular.module('fooApp', [
    'ngResource',
     'restangular'
  ]);

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Not seeing a problem with those versions loaded in that order in [this Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/lT9o3Qv6f8Rcw2RlLQyh?p=preview). You're not seeing any other errors in console? Are you seeing the source for Angular and then Restangular load in the Network tab of your browser's dev tools?

Comment: In the network tab I'm seeing angular.js and angular-resource.js being loaded but not restangular.js or lodash.js.  In the console all I see is "uncaught object"

Comment: You said that you are seeing those files in your `bower_components` directory, but it sounds like it's not able to load Restangular. Are you 100% sure it's in the right place? If you swap out that line with `<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/restangular/1.3.1/restangular.js"></script>` I bet it works.

Comment: I tried that also ... still the same problem.

Comment: Might be better to move this to [**chat**](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/54463/angularjs-1-2-15-and-restangular-1-3-1-problem).

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Marc Kline's help I finally got things working. Here's what I had to do:

```
yo angular foo
bower install lodash --save
bower install restangular --save
grunt bowerInstall
npm install karma-jasmine --save-dev
npm install karma-chrome-launcher --save-dev
npm install
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue to this, and the problem was due to the fact that I hasn't added the Lodash and Rectangular JS assets to my Karma test config.

Adding `lodash.compat.min.js` and `restangular.min.js` to the files array in `karma.conf.js` made my tests run correctly.